# how to query to a collection with array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I Have An Array With 4 Object Items I want query to my collection and return 4 items that have this uid's...

```
myArray = > [{uid : 'test'},{uid : 'test2'},{uid : 'test3'},{uid : 'test4'}]

ProductCollection.find({????},(err,result)=>{})
```

**NOTE : I dont want use any loop**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont want use any loop

I will assume that's related to query the DB several times, one for each `uid` value.

Anyway, you can go to the database once to filter elements that match an array of values, like your case, using MongoDB's [`$in` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

But you would have to format the `uid` values to an array of the values themselves instead of the array of objets, this can be accomplished with a simple `.map` call (don't know if you will consider this a loop) to get the filter value in the correct format.

```
var uids = myArray.map((item) => item.uid })
// ['test', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
```

And after that you can query your DB with this uids values

```
ProductCollection.find({'uid': {'$in': uids} },(err,result)=>{})
```

(Assuming `'uid'` it the property you have in your `ProductCollection` that you are trying to filter by)